# Long text area in formula work around not working

Tags: formula, long-text-area

**There is a workaround using workflows as mentioned [here](http://linkingto.blogspot.de/2011/08/salesforce-long-text-area-and-formulas.html).**
I've had trouble getting this to work in my scenario, was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this.
**I have two objects**:
 1. Price List Item
 2. Summary Output
I have a long text field on the ‘Price List Item’.
Then I have a formula on the ‘Summary Output’ that needs to pull in the long text from the ‘Price List Item’ to output to a proposal output from the summary output.
I’ve tried several configurations based on what was outlined to no avail. Could anyone clarify considering this scenario?

Comment: so I assume you want some sort of concatenation of price item texts into a field on the associated parent output object? If so , are you certain formulas are the best approach ? Would a trigger on the price item provide an easier solution?

Comment: I'm not sure, no there is no concatenation on the text. We just have a need for more than the 255 char limit on the standard text area, so the only way to get the long text through a formula is with a workaround. I'm not well versed on triggers so am unsure the benefits or use in the issue. Thanks for your feedback, if a trigger can do the job I would certainly like to try.

Comment: How the objects are related (what has the lookup to what; I assume you have lookup from Summary Output to the price list item?)

Comment: Yes sir, the Summary Output is where I've been able to do a Formula text area (255) with successful look-up to the Price List Item table. So with the workaround I'm trying to get it to pull in the long text area.

Comment: I tried the workaround in your link and it works fine. The target field in Summary_Output can't be a formula field, it has to be a long text field. In your WF Field Update, are you using the option 'Use a formula to set the new value' and then clicking the Formula Editor? The 'insert field' button will bring up the long text field on the lookup (Price List Item).  The WF workaround is copying the value from one record to another. N.B. If the price_list_item field changes (e.g. to correct typos), it won't propagate into the Summary_Output

Comment: Thanks crop1645, you got me thinking so I backed away from my custom objects and tried just between standard objects to confirm that it would work, and indeed it did. The reason I think it's not working on the 3rd party custom objects is that the one we are trying to get the field updated to is a rollup summary and doesn't really ever get touched, created or updated so won't trigger the update, and it runs dynamically to generate our quotes. Also the parent to child relationship may be to far apart, since it is a 3rd party app, I'm not sure.

Comment: I finally got this to work with a workflow rule to update the Price List Item objects Full Description (custom field long text) with the Product objects (standard field long text) Product Description. The only thing I need to resolve now is how to do a mass touch on all the Price List Item records to force them to do an update to trigger the workflow rule. I think I will pose this in another question to the Stack Exchange.